# Fetchind data from Json array

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Trying get my json data from web api with volley.

My Json data:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":3,
         "title":"Bakı şəhər Mədəniyyət Baş İdarəsi",
         "icon":{
            "data":{
               "full_url":"http:\/\/app.digitello.agency\/public\/uploads\/_\/originals\/turkey-marmara-region-flag-turkish-regions-by-sergoali-dan65pv-fullview.jpg",
               "url":"\/uploads\/_\/originals\/turkey-marmara-region-flag-turkish-regions-by-sergoali-dan65pv-fullview.jpg",
               "thumbnails":[
                  {
                     "url":"http:\/\/app.digitello.agency\/public\/thumbnail\/_\/200\/200\/crop\/good\/turkey-marmara-region-flag-turkish-regions-by-sergoali-dan65pv-fullview.jpg",
                     "relative_url":"\/thumbnail\/_\/200\/200\/crop\/good\/turkey-marmara-region-flag-turkish-regions-by-sergoali-dan65pv-fullview.jpg",
                     "dimension":"200x200",
                     "width":200,
                     "height":200
                  }
               ],
               "embed":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "title":"Sumqayıt Regioal Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "title":"Xaçmaz Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":6,
         "title":"İsmayıllı Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":7,
         "title":"Şəki Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":8,
         "title":"Kürdəmir Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":9,
         "title":"Ağstafa Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":10,
         "title":"Şəmkir Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":11,
         "title":"Gəncə Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":12,
         "title":"Bərdə Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":13,
         "title":"Ağcabədi Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":14,
         "title":"Ağdaş Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":15,
         "title":"Sabirabad Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":16,
         "title":"Biləsuvar Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":17,
         "title":"Masallı Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      },
      {
         "id":18,
         "title":"Lənkəran Regional Mədəniyyət İdarəsi",
         "icon":null
      }
   ],
   "public":true
}
```

My adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    //Imageloader to load images
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    //Context
    private Context context;

    //Array List that would contain the urls and the titles for the images
    private ArrayList<String> images;
    private ArrayList<String> names;

    public GridViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> images, ArrayList<String> names){
        //Getting all the values
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return images.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Creating a linear layout
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        //NetworkImageView
        NetworkImageView networkImageView = new NetworkImageView(context);

        //Initializing ImageLoader
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(images.get(position), ImageLoader.getImageListener(networkImageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        //Setting the image url to load
        networkImageView.setImageUrl(images.get(position),imageLoader);

        //Creating a textview to show the title
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(names.get(position));

        //Scaling the imageview
        networkImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        networkImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,200));

        //Adding views to the layout
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        linearLayout.addView(networkImageView);

        //Returnint the layout
        return linearLayout;
    }
}
```

And my fragment view:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.mct.virtualcultureguide.GridViewAdapter;
import com.mct.virtualcultureguide.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RegionsFragment extends Fragment {
    //Web api url
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://app.digitello.agency/public/_/items/regions?limit=-1&fields=id,title,icon.data";
    //Tag values to read from json
    public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "icon";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "title";
    //GridView Object
    private GridView gridView;
    //ArrayList for Storing image urls and titles
    private ArrayList<String> images;
    private ArrayList<String> names;

    public RegionsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_regions, container, false);
        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.GridView);

        images = new ArrayList<>();
        names = new ArrayList<>();

        //Calling the getData method
        getData();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void getData(){
        //Showing a progress dialog while our app fetches the data from url
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show((Context) getActivity(), "Please wait...","Fetching data...",false,false);

        //Creating a json array request to get the json from our api
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Dismissing the progressdialog on response
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //Displaying our grid
                        showGrid(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        );

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue((Context) getActivity());
        //Adding our request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    private void showGrid(JSONArray jsonArray){
        //Looping through all the elements of json array
        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            //Creating a json object of the current index
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                //getting json object from current index
                obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                //getting image url and title from json object
                images.add(obj.getString(TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                names.add(obj.getString(TAG_NAME));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //Creating GridViewAdapter Object
        GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter((Context) getActivity(),images,names);

        //Adding adapter to gridview
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    }

}
```

I need get content in my json, where all collected in data container, also need thumbnail url in icon row. I trying add JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json.getString("data")); but its not work.
Using Directus for json api, trying get only thumbnail url with field param in url icon.data.thumbnails.url, only work icon.data with all params in icon container.

Answer (score 0):

from your json data i guess your **"data"**  is a json object, inside it is an array. Change your *//Creating a json array request to get the json from our api* to create a json object request

Comment: Can you give me little example plz? I understand what needs to be done but I don’t know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You must use JsonObjectRequest since the first character of the response is `{`

From there, you must use `response.getJsonArray("data")`

Comment: Can you give me little example plz? I understand what needs to be done but I don’t know how to do it

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request